# outputing 4k@60hz on UB15.04

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

After setting up the OS with a normal display because it was flickering I changed to the Nvidia 346.59drivers(`nvidia-346-updates`, I have a Gtx970).

I plugged in the 4k TV but the refresh rate was off its currently set  up at 30hz I tried to ypus xrand with both cvt and gtf I saw small differences in the values I created new modes but wasn't able to add them 
xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1280mm x 720mm
1920x1080      60.0 +   59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     24.0     60.0     50.0
3840x2160      30.0*    25.0     24.0 
1680x1050      60.0
1600x1200      60.0
1440x900       59.9 
1400x1050      60.0
1280x1024      60.0 
1280x960       60.0 
1280x800       59.8 
1280x720       59.9     50.0 
1024x768       60.0 
800x600        60.3 
720x576        50.0     50.1
720x480        59.9     60.1 
640x480        59.9     59.9 
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Unknown-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3840x2160_60.00 (0x210)  712.8MHz
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock  134.2KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2237           clock   60.0Hz
  3840x2160_59.00 (0x212)  700.5MHz
        h: width  3840 start 4160 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock  131.9KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2163 end 2168 total 2236           clock   59.0Hz
  g3840x2160_59.00 (0x213)  699.8MHz
        h: width  3840 start 4152 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock  131.7KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2161 end 2164 total 2233           clock   59.0Hz
  g3840x2160_60.00 (0x214)  712.3MHz
        h: width  3840 start 4152 end 4576 total 5312 skew    0 clock  134.1KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2161 end 2164 total 2235           clock   60.0Hz
```

when I try to add the mode to HDMI-0 I get this output:

```
xrandr --verbose --addmode HDMI-0 "g3840x2160_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  48
```

Comment: i tried compiz setting manager also there it says that the screen is running at 60 hz